# How to store output of a loop when resampling of parameter values for simultaneous equations in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, differential-equations

I have a code that evaluates parameter values for 4 simultaneous equations. I'm particularly interested to store all the parameter combinations when a + b (stored in results$ab) is greater than 3000. If it is greater than 3000, then it's coded as "Yes". I want to write a for-loop that will loop through the code to check for if a + b > 3000 and store the corresponding values. Then, I want the program to loop 1000 times, and store the parameter values for corresponding "Yes". I am trying to store the output, but it's not yielding me any results.

```
x <- seq(from = 0.0001, to = 1000, by = 0.1)
t <- seq(from = 0.0001, to = 1000, by = 0.1)
v <- seq(from = 0.0001, to = 1000, by = 0.1)
w <- seq(from = 0.0001, to = 1000, by = 0.1)
n <- seq(from = 0.0001, to = 1000, by = 0.1)
f <- seq(from = 0.0001, to = 1000, by = 0.1)


  values <- list(x = x, t = t, v = v, w = w, n = n, f = f)
  for(i in 1:1000){
    eqs <- list(
      a = expression(x * t - 2 * x),
      b = expression(v - x^2), 
      c = expression(x - w*t - t*t), 
      d = expression((n - f)/t)
    )

    for(i in 1:1000){
    samples <- 10000
    values.sampled <- lapply(values, sample, samples)
    results[i] <- sapply(eqs, eval, envir = values.sampled)
    results[i] <- data.frame(results)
    results$ab[i] <- results$a[i] + results$b[i]
    results$binary[i] <- ifelse(results$ab[i] > 3000, "Yes","No")
    output[i] <- results[results$binary=="Yes",]

  }

what <- as.list(output)
```

Comment: You can't use array indexing notation in list names, so a[i] = expression(...) is incorrect. Also for every iteration i, the values in the x, t, v, ... vectors are the same - so why repeat them 1000 times?

Are you trying to sample various values of x, t, v, ..., compute a, b, c, d, and then work out which combinations of those x, t,.. ended up with a + b>3000? Could you possibly do a constrained optimisation - find values of x, t, ... such that a + b > 3000?

Comment: You are right. It looks like I'll have to loop the sampling various values of x,t,v to compute a,b,c,d that give me a + b > 3000. I don't know how to do a constrained optimisation method

Comment: Why are there two `for` loops? And is one really nested inside the other? Either way, one of them is missing the closing bracket.

Comment: When does `results` first get defined? I'm getting an error at `results[i] <- sapply(eqs, eval, envir = values.sampled)`. Please use `reprex` to ensure that you have a working example.

Answer (score 4):

`a+b` is equal to `(x * t - 2 * x) + (v - x^2)`, which is just a quadratic in `x`, so you can solve `a+b>3000` analytically for `x`, `v` and `t`.

The inequality is `x^2 + (2-t)x + (3000-v) < 0`.

Substitute `T = 2-t` and `V = 3000-v`, then `x^2 + Tx + V < 0`.

For this to have any values less than zero, it must have two real roots, which implies that 
`T^2 - 4V > 0` - i.e `V < (T^2)/4`. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)

Given `T` and `V` satisfying this inequality, the values of `x` for which `a+b>3000` are those between the roots of the quadratic, i.e. `|2x+T| < sqrt(T^2 - 4V)`.

So if you want a selection of values that satisfy the condition, it should be straightforward to loop through a range of values of `t`, pick a value of `v` that satisfies `V < (T^2)/4`, and then pick an `x` that falls in the appropriate range.

Here is one way...

```
t <- 1:1000
T <- 2 - t
V <- sapply((T ^ 2) / 4, function(z) runif(min = 0, max = z, n = 1)) #assumes V>0 (???)
v <- 3000 - V
x <- (sapply(sqrt(T ^ 2 - 4 * V), function(z) runif(min = -z, max = z, n = 1)) - T) / 2
ab <- (x * t - 2 * x) + (v - x ^ 2) #all >3000 (except for t=2, where ab=3000 exactly)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) solution that relies on brute force - all combinations of `x` and `t` as well as combinations of `x` and `v` are evaluated:

```
library(data.table)
# create data
dt <- as.data.table(replicate(6, seq(from = 0.001, to = 1000, by = 1), simplify = F))
names(dt) <- c('x', 't','v','w','n','f')

# if your data.frame has all the combinations you want:
dt[, lapply(eqs, eval, envir = .SD)][, a_b := a + b][]

# This does all of the combinations for eqs a and b - takes 22 seconds for 10,000 rows
dt[, {x_t = CJ(x,t)
      x_v = CJ(x,v)
      a_b = eval(eqs$a, envir = x_t) + eval(eqs$b, envir = x_v)
      output = a_b > 3000L
      list(x = x_t[[1]], t = x_t[[2]], v = x_v[[2]], ab = a_b, output = output)
      }
   ][output == T,]

              x       t       v       ab output
     1:   3.001 754.001 754.001 3001.750   TRUE
     2:   3.001 755.001 755.001 3005.751   TRUE
     3:   3.001 756.001 756.001 3009.752   TRUE
     4:   3.001 757.001 757.001 3013.753   TRUE
     5:   3.001 758.001 758.001 3017.754   TRUE
    ---                                        
479045: 992.001 998.001 998.001 4966.005   TRUE
479046: 992.001 999.001 999.001 5959.006   TRUE
479047: 993.001 998.001 998.001 3977.004   TRUE
479048: 993.001 999.001 999.001 4971.005   TRUE
479049: 994.001 999.001 999.001 3981.004   TRUE
```

Comment: Can you please explain what CJ[x_t] is? Also, when I run this output, I get Empty data.table (0 rows) of 5 cols: x,t,v,ab,output

Comment: @Biotechgeek ```CJ()``` is very similar to ```expand.grid()``` in that it's a cartesian product of two vectors. Your comment is ```CJ[x_t]``` which is just one vector. My code is ```x_t = CJ(x, t)```.

Answer (score 2):

Based mostly on your description, here's a tidyverse solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

n_samples_per_trial <- 1e4
n_trials            <- 1e3
variable_ranges     <- seq(from = 0.0001, to = 1000, by = 0.1)
cutoff              <- 3e3

result_list <- rerun(.n = n_trials, {

  rerun(.n = 6, {
    sample(variable_ranges, n_samples_per_trial, replace = TRUE)
  }) %>% 
    as_tibble(.name_repair = ~ c("x", "t", "v", "w", "n", "f")) %>% 
    mutate(a      = x * t - 2 * x,
           b      = v - x^2,
           c      = x - w*t - t*t,
           d      = (n - f)/t,
           ab     = a + b,
           binary = if_else(ab > cutoff, "Yes", "No")) %>% 
    filter(binary == "Yes")

})

result_list %>% head(2) %>% glimpse()
#> List of 2
#>  $ :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    4840 obs. of  12 variables:
#>   ..$ x     : num [1:4840] 720.7 22.9 44.7 20.7 10.6 ...
#>   ..$ t     : num [1:4840] 794 325 768 400 531 ...
#>   ..$ v     : num [1:4840] 172 962 853 901 264 ...
#>   ..$ w     : num [1:4840] 842.8 274.3 18.9 957.2 321.8 ...
#>   ..$ n     : num [1:4840] 605 322 671 890 965 ...
#>   ..$ f     : num [1:4840] 397 557 299 691 825 ...
#>   ..$ a     : num [1:4840] 570795 7397 34222 8245 5604 ...
#>   ..$ b     : num [1:4840] -519236 437 -1145 473 152 ...
#>   ..$ c     : num [1:4840] -1298899 -194750 -603673 -543387 -452411 ...
#>   ..$ d     : num [1:4840] 0.261 -0.723 0.486 0.497 0.264 ...
#>   ..$ ab    : num [1:4840] 51558 7834 33077 8718 5756 ...
#>   ..$ binary: chr [1:4840] "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" ...
#>  $ :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    4815 obs. of  12 variables:
#>   ..$ x     : num [1:4815] 400 806 410 477 169 ...
#>   ..$ t     : num [1:4815] 992 938 893 573 257 ...
#>   ..$ v     : num [1:4815] 453 773 456 279 933 ...
#>   ..$ w     : num [1:4815] 778 254 189 183 784 ...
#>   ..$ n     : num [1:4815] 629 811 411 529 667 ...
#>   ..$ f     : num [1:4815] 903 330 995 908 340 ...
#>   ..$ a     : num [1:4815] 395543 754765 365563 271843 43214 ...
#>   ..$ b     : num [1:4815] -159307 -649186 -167726 -226773 -27764 ...
#>   ..$ c     : num [1:4815] -1754435 -1117341 -966696 -431818 -267523 ...
#>   ..$ d     : num [1:4815] -0.277 0.513 -0.654 -0.662 1.275 ...
#>   ..$ ab    : num [1:4815] 236236 105579 197837 45070 15450 ...
#>   ..$ binary: chr [1:4815] "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" ...
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Let me know if I misunderstand the goal.